# Android Emulator Freezing On Startup

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run an Android emulator on Ubuntu 11.10 x64 with Eclipse 3.7. I have installed the SDK, the plugin for Eclipse, have set my PATH variables to include the android-sdk paths, installed the 32 bit libraries, and have created an AVD to run. When I go to Debug or Run however, my system hangs on:

`Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched`

I have seen other people hang and the solution is usually "check the Logcat" (I have no message here), "add a value for the SD Card in the AVD" (I have done this) or "Wait a while - it will happen eventually" (I let it run over night and still no dice).

Are there any other ideas? Thanks so much!

EDIT:

I should also mention that I have tried relaunching the application which was another commonly suggested solution. Also, the view for the emulator launches, but I never get anything inside of the emulator window (I never see A N D R O I D for example) in case this helps.

Here is the result of `-verbose`

```
emulator: found SDK root at /home/devon/android-sdks
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 8
emulator: found skin 'WVGA800' in directory: /home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin WVGA800
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/skins
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/devon/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/skins/WVGA800/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/images//kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/images//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/images//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 128MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = 
  hw.ramSize = 128
  hw.touchScreen = yes
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = yes
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.camera = no
  hw.camera.maxHorizontalPixels = 640
  hw.camera.maxVerticalPixels = 480
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 240
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.fakeCamera = back
  hw.webcam.count = 6
  hw.webcam.0.name = webcam0
  hw.webcam.1.name = webcam1
  hw.webcam.2.name = webcam2
  hw.webcam.3.name = webcam3
  hw.webcam.4.name = webcam4
  hw.webcam.5.name = webcam5
  hw.webcam.0.direction = front
  hw.webcam.1.direction = back
  hw.webcam.2.direction = front
  hw.webcam.3.direction = front
  hw.webcam.4.direction = front
  hw.webcam.5.direction = front
  vm.heapSize = 24
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  kernel.path = /home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/images//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/images//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/images//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 78m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 66m
  disk.snapStorage.path = 
  avd.name = Test
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/home/devon/android-sdks/tools/emulator-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "/home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /home/devon/android-sdks/tools/emulator-arm -android-hw /home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x4e00000,initfile=/home/devon/android-sdks/platforms/android-8/images//system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-devon/emulator-wbKapY
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 4e1e000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x4200000,file=/home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '24m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/devon/.android/avd/Test.avd/cache.img
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: Trace file name is not set

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: can't connect to ADB server: Connection refused
emulator: ping program: /home/devon/android-sdks/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /home/devon/android-sdks/tools/ddms ping emulator 15.0
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Ubuntu... but have you tried to launch the AVD firstly, via AVD manager for instance, and then run/debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with VirtualBox (didn't think to mention this, sorry). Unchecking `3D Acceleration` caused the emulator to run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting your emulator on the command line by this command :
(cd to your tools folder of your android sdk before that)

emulator -avd avdname

Comment: emulator -avd avdname -verbose give you a bit more information about what is happening

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was while the emulator stuck on Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched.
 Launch your app again.and now it will start installing your app.

or you can try starting emulator from AVD manager.

Comment: I had previously tried to launch the app again and forgot to mention it. I will try to launch it from the AVD Manager and get back to you.

Comment: if the problem persist then delete the all emulator from AVD and create a fresh one for your app.

Comment: When I try to delete an AVD I get the message "The Android Virtual Device [Name] is currently running in an emulator and cannot be deleted". I get this message even on a fresh reboot, so I am not sure what the problem is.