# Android emulator crashes; "emulator-arm.exe stopped responding"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm attempting to write my first android app, HelloAndroid. The error in the title occurs whenever I try to run it on the emulator. This reliably happens with any AVD I create, and when I launch the AVD itself before running the app.

---

**Edit**: 
Running the app on a real device works fine.

Also, running the emulator from command line with the `-verbose` option shows that the emulator hangs after the following:

`emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'`.

(Using an AVD with or without the camera enabled has no effect.)

---

Here's what I'm using for Android development:

- Windows 7 (64 bit)
- JDK 1.7.0
- Eclipse 3.7.1 (64 bit)
- Android SDK / AVD Manager, r16
- ADT Plugin 16.0.0
- AVD Manager

Here are potential solutions I've found on this site and others that I've tried so far (without success):

- Ensuring that there are no spaces in the path to the SDK (i.e., installing the SDK directly to the C:\ drive)
- Fresh install of Eclipse, Android SDK / AVD Manager, and the ADT plugin
- Running a 32 bit version of Eclipse
- Ensuring that Eclipse runs using the latest version of the JDK by changing the -vm path
- Changing the resolution of the AVD
- Deleting and re-creating an AVD

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit:** additional steps taken without success:

- Running Eclipse as an administrator
- Creating JAVA_HOME environment variable and setting value to path to JDK bin directory
- Using JDK 1.6 (for both eclipse and Windows)
- Running the emulator with no audio (recording or playback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue; it's not a bug at all.

As it turns out, I had a program called ATI Tray Tools running in the background to manage my graphics card, and this was causing the error (and several other errors with other programs unrelated to Android development). Disabling this program solved the issue.
A very irritating and trivial problem... glad it's fixed.

Thank you for your suggestions, everyone!

Comment: It remminds me of this problem with Virtual Box 3D Acceleration and Emulator freezing on start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066123/android-emulator-freezing-on-startup

Answer (score 2):

Emulator crashes because it fails to allocate memory.  Follow these steps to resolve the problem.

1. Go to Window->Android Virtual Device Manager.
2. Select your virtual emulator under "Android Virtual Devices" tab.
3. Click "Edit" option which will open a new window.
4. After, reduce RAM memory under "Memory options"

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughs:

- Have you try running Eclipse as an Administrator (likely)
- Did you set PATH and JAVA_HOME* env variables correctly (long shot)
- Have try using JDK 1.6 (likely)
- Kill the emulator and re-runnit(likely)
- Just as @Rahul suggested you can try to install Android in a spaceless Folder ie. (C:\Program Files Try C:) (likely)

You might want to take a look at a problem I had a back ago and wrote a post about it on my [blog](http://www.necronet.info/2009/06/emulador-android-cuelga-al-cerrar.html). Altough is in spanish here is basicly it's a two step process idea:

JAVA_HOME should be the path where Android is installed as C:\Program Files\AndroidSDK\

Kill the emulator in your case you should terminate the process:

```
 killall emulator -9
```

And runn the emulator without the audio:

```
emulator -audio none
```

But this solution was specific for linux and a problem with media back then.

Interesting thread:

[Emulator freezing on start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066123/android-emulator-freezing-on-startup)

Comment: I recommend to try JDK 1.6 at first. This, to my opinion, should help.

Comment: Just to be sure, what is the correct value for the JAVA_HOME variable? This variable did not exist when I checked, so I created it and set the value to point to the JDK bin directory.

Comment: JAVA_HOME it's where java folder is, for example C:\Program Files\Java or /usr/local/jvm/java_jdk1.6/

Comment: As I thought. Unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue either. Thanks though!

Comment: try running the emulator from console with the following command emulator -avd <avd_name> -verbose, 

does this happen only with the emulator have you tested with a real device?

Comment: None of the possibilities solved the problem (see the edit to my question). Yes, this only happens with the emulator; everything works fine with a real device. I tried doing as you suggested with the -verbose command: the result is that the emulator fails after the `emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'`. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, I've tried using an AVD with the camera both enabled and disabled; neither works.

Comment: can you try to run the command as Administrator, but yours seem like this bug can you vote up to fix it.... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21060&thanks=21060&ts=1319207835

Comment: There is also someone who did a patch for this unresolved issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20952#c9

Comment: As you can see I edited the question earlier to reflect that I've tried running it as an administrator (and everything else you suggested).

Comment: Please answer if you already know how to solve the problem, not by posting alternative solution without knowing which one is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try doing as Necronet and Yury say. Added to that, ensure that you don't have your Android installed in C:/Program Files. Instead install it in C:/ directly.

Comment: Thanks! I had faced a weird problem with Android and then experimented this to find out that this itself was the solution.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a common problem. It was one of the first things I tried; Doesn't seem to be the answer in my case, unfortunately.

Comment: Please answer if you already know how to solve the problem, not by posting "your suggestion", that will not help the asker.

Comment: @dns: The person who has posted the question didn't find any objection with my "suggestion" and neither did others. This question also has an answer accepted already. Don't you think that a comment on a 1.5 year old question and answer doesn't make any sense now?

Answer (score 0):

**Its may be RAM error. Do this.**

1. Close emulator
2. Go into AVD folder (eg. C:\Users\username.android\avd\phone.avd)
3. open config.ini file

   modify disk.dataPartition.size from M to MB, suppose its value is 512M then change it to 512MB

   do same for hw.ramSize from 512M to 512MB

   If you have storage sd card then also change sdcard.size from 10M to 10MB
4. Start emulator again. You must do this for all your emulators.
   This works for me.