# Android emulator crashes with hardware acceleration and phone app

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an app that uses a a paint flag to set strike-through on a `TextView`. This application works fine on the emulator until I enable `GPU Rendering` on the Android 4.03 AVD.

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

Once this is enabled, the entire emulator locks up and no longer responds the moment I set the paint flag.

```
TextView message = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message);
message.setPaintFlags(day.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

This is inside of a `ListView` adapter and on load, it calls the **getView(...)** method and hits the **setPaintFlags(...)** method 6 times and crashes after the 6th time.

If I comment out the **setPaintFlags(...)** line, it doesn't crash. If I install this on the phone, the app crashes once I trigger the strike-through to occur.

I've set this on the manifest solves the issue on the emulator, but still crashes on the phone.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
```

Does anyone have experience with this crashing on the phone, but not the emulator (unless it's hardware accelerated).

I've dug around and found other similar postings [Android emulator crashes; "emulator-arm.exe stopped responding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627098/android-emulator-crashes-emulator-arm-exe-stopped-responding) but in my case, it crashes on the phone too.

**Solution** Turned out to be a coincidence and was unrelated to the acceleration. Null pointer found via LogCat.

Comment: Is it a force-close crash? If so, please provide the LogCat output.

Comment: It's an emulator not responding crash. The Windows app freezes and need to close the emulator

Comment: Forgot that you could get LogCat from the phone. Turns out the issue on the phone was unrelated to the acceleration. Post an answer about checking LogCat on the phone and I'll accept it

Comment: Done! Glad you've made some progress. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As per comments above*:

Since the emulator is fine, and it's the phone device crashing, use USB debugging to get the LogCat output. This will help to narrow down the cause of the crash/error.